# error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before function_name

Tags: c, gcc, msp430

Here is the error:

```
msp430-gcc -mmcu=msp430g2553 -Os   -c -o gpio_test.o gpio_test.c
In file included from msp430_lib.h:9:0,
                 from gpio_test.c:4:
gpio_api.h:20:6: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘gpio_init’
gpio_api.h:27:6: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘gpio_ioctl_pull_en’
gpio_api.h:35:6: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘gpio_write’
make: *** [gpio_test.o] Error 1
```

Here is the header file where the error is coming from(The line numbers don't match up because I stripped all the comments out of the file to shorten it):

```
/* gpio_api.h - General Purpose Input/Output API
*/

#ifndef MSP_GPIO_API_H
#define MSP_GPIO_API_H

#include  <msp430g2553.h>

#define INPUT   0
#define OUTPUT  1
#define DOWN    0
#define UP      1

bool gpio_init(int port, int pin, int direction);

bool gpio_ioctl_pull_en(int port, int pin, int direction);

bool gpio_write(int port, int pin, int value);

int  gpio_read (int port, int pin);

#endif
```

It seems simple enough, yet I can't figure out what my problem is.

Comment: So... does this header require C++ ?

Comment: I don't think so, but that's a real possibility.  I've compiled code that included that file using the identical make file (changed object names only).

Comment: In this case, removing the comments was bad because the line numbers (20, 27, 35) is the most useful information you got from the compiler. In the future, you should assume that whatever is at the reported line and column is somehow broken.

Comment: @WhozCraig has a point. check if you are trying c compiler on c++ code

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You have to include `<stdbool.h>` in your program. `bool` is actually a macro defined in `stdbool.h` header file.

Comment: The error message OP got could have been a bit more... descriptive.